# ¿Cómo obtener el nombre de la ciudad actual por medio de MapBox?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mapbox, mapa

Soy nuevo en el uso de apis de MapBox, me gustaría colocar el marcador en un área del mapa, y al momento de hacerlo obtener el departamento, provincia, distrito y la dirección donde me encuentro. No encontré algo similar en la documentación, podrían ayudarme con este tema? También quisiera delimitar el mapa que muestro, es decir que solo me habilite una parte del mapa y fuera de el no me permita marcar nada.

Comment: Puedes comenzar viendo la documentación para hacer [reverse geocoding](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/#reverse-geocoding)

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy amplia, necesitas hacer preguntas que se enfoquen en problemas mas pequenos y especificos, tambien ayuda que muestres el codigo y expliques el error que tienes.

Answer (score 0):

si estas usando un marcador puedes obtener la lat y lng de dicho marcador, primero creas el marcador:

```
const marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
  draggable: true,
})
  .setLngLat([lng, lat])
  .addTo(this.map);
```

y con la siguiente función del marcador podrás obtener la lat y lng

```
marker.getLngLat()
```

Luego de tener la lat y lng puedes usar geocodificación inversa de mapbox haciendo una consulta get:

```
https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${lng},${lat}.json?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN
```

Puedes acceder a la doc aquí [reverse-geocoding](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/geocoding/#reverse-geocoding)

Con esto puedes obtener las direcciones asociadas a esa georeferencia